# How to get String from another activity?

Tags: android, string, imageview

I just wanna make my imageview load from url when it click then displaying in another activity.

**Here my adapter class**

```
    private void openDetailActivity(String name, String propellant, String desc, String imageUrl)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);

    //PACK DATA
    i.putExtra("NAME_KEY",name);
    i.putExtra("PROPELLANT_KEY",propellant);
    i.putExtra("DESCRIPTION_KEY",desc);
    i.putExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY",imageUrl);

    c.startActivity(i);
}
```

**then opened in Detail acitivity with this code**

```
 Intent i=this.getIntent();
String imageurl=i.getExtras().getString("IMAGEURL_KEY");
        touchimg = imageurl;
```

and i make setonClicklistener, when it clicked so the image can load with full size in another layout.
**Here the code**

```
            Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, enlarge.class);
            i.putExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY",touchimg);//PENTING UNTUK AMBIL DATA
            startActivity(i);
```

**And the last, this class below for catch url image to display** 
**enlarge.class**

```
String touchimg  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("IMAGEURL_KEY");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_touchimageview);
    ImageView imglarge1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglarge);
    Picasso.with(this).load(touchimg).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imglarge1);

}
```

And i got error with this log message :

```
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at com.newsapp.unair.rizki.enlarge.<init>(enlarge.java:18)
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2116)
```

How can i fix it?

i've check with Log.d, when i put Log below  get,Intent like this

```
Intent i=this.getIntent();
    String imageurl=i.getExtras().getString("IMAGEURL_KEY");
    touchimg = imageurl;
    if(touchimg != null)
        Log.d("TAG", "tidak null");
    else
        Log.d("TAG", "image null"):
```

and the Log said "tidak null" or not Null, but if when the Log.d i put inside onClick like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, enlarge.class);
                i.putExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY",touchimg);
                startActivity(i);
                if(touchimg != null)
                    Log.d("TAGput", "tidak null");
                else
                    Log.d("TAGput", "image null");
```

the Log doesnt appear nothing, what is that mean?

Comment: post you enlarge Activity code

Comment: i've just update

Comment: are you sure when you are setting Picasso.with(this).load(touchimg) , touchimg is not null ?

Comment: how can i check that if touchimg is not null? touchimg is take from i.putExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY",touchimg);

Comment: i've update my question @ApoorvSingh

Answer (score 2):

## Try This

- In your case, in activity2, before going to activity1, you will store a String this way :

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity1.class);
  intent.putExtra("message", message);
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- get the value like this

  ```
    Intent i = getIntent();
      if (i.hasExtra("message")){
       String value = i.getStringExtra("message");   
       }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, enlarge.class);
i.putExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY",getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY"));//PENTING UNTUK AMBIL DATA
        startActivity(i);
```

and

```
String touchimg  = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY");

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_touchimageview);
  ImageView imglarge1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglarge);
   Picasso.with(this).load(touchimg).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imglarge1);
}
```

Check in enlarge.class.

Comment: still got the error with this log :  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.newsapp.unair.rizki.enlarge.<init>(enlarge.java:16)

Comment: @RizkiDeddySusanto  , please check edited answer  hope it work

Comment: still get NullPointerException